# evaluate stripos(), what is the difference between !== FALSE and === TRUE?

Tags: php, evaluate, stripos

I have this issue with a string:

```
$val = 'NOT NULL';

if(stripos($val, 'NULL') !== FALSE){
    echo "IS $val";
}
```

It evaluates fine, but if I use `=== TRUE` as evaluator, things go wrong.
The answer eludes me, please help me understand.

Comment: `===` is strict comparison i.e. matches types as well. Since `stripos` returns integer and integer !== boolean `stripos(...) === true` evaluates to `false`.

Comment: thank you! indeed, it's obvious now... but for some reason, I was stuck in a faulty logic.

Comment: in php integers are also treated as boolean and in case of `strpos` and `stipos` it returns integer (also string offset starts with 0). and `===` is strict comparison i.e. `0` is not equal to `false` and `1 or more` is not equal to `true`.

Comment: @punk , i see... it's tricky. So, if I would use `==` as long as offset would be >0, I would get `TRUE`, but if offset =0, I would get a misleading `FALSE`. Now it's clear that only comparing against strict `FALSE`, I can get the true result.

Answer (score 8):

If you read the documentation for [`stripos()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stripos.php) you'll find.

> Returns the position of where the needle exists relative to the beginnning of the haystack string (independent of offset). Also note that string positions start at 0, and not 1.
>
> Returns `FALSE` if the needle was not found.

It does not return `TRUE`. Since you are using [strict equality](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php), your condition will never be *true*.

If you did `stripos($val, 'NULL') == TRUE` then your code would execute if `NULL` were found at position `0` - since PHP will do some *type-juggling* and effectively `0 == (int)true`.

The appropriate way to test for existence using `stripos()` is what you have:

```
if (stripos($val, 'NULL') !== FALSE){
    echo "IS $val";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer is because you are using the strict equality operator.  The function itself returns an int (or boolean if the needle is not found).  The return value is not equal (in the strict sense, both value *and* type) to true, which is why the check fails.

Answer (score 1):

Since `===` and `!==` are [strict comparison operators](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php) - `!== false` is not the same as `===true` since, for example, `1!==false` is ok (values and types are not equal), but `1===true` is not ok (values are equal, but types are not).

This sample indicates the meaning of strict comparison - i.e. not only values matters, but also types of compared data.